# Reset or switch style after duration

Tags: html, css

i have info bar div on top of my page i change div size and position like this

```css
.info {
  background-color : #e2efbb;
  padding          : 30px 40px;
  height           : 25%;
  width            : 18%;
  position         : fixed;
  right            : 1.9%;
  bottom           : 0px;
  border-radius    : 10px;
  box-shadow       : 0px 0px 30px #999;
  text-align       : center;
  z-index          : 1;
}
```

I need to reset this style to get dive back to normal position and width after 10 seconds.
how can i do it with CSS only.

Comment: https://muffinman.io/blog/css-animations-instead-of-js-timers/ 

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use css animations to do this.
For example you can change the div after 10 seconds like this:

```
 @keyframes example {
    0% {width:100px;}
    100% {width:300px;}
}
.info {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-name: example;
}
```

The animation starts when html element has this line:

```
animation-name: example;
```

So, if you add this line on hover, you can add some user interaction, if you need it.

It's compatible with all browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20animation